# Using C# to extract Facebook data

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-c#-sdk

I have just started to develop an application for Facebook. I searched a lot in the internet but I could not find any comprehensive answer to my questions. I really hope that someone can help me. I have below questions:

**Background:**
I am developing a web application and I have registered my web application in Facebook and I have got my AppID and Secret. My requirement is to

1. Extract friend's list of users registered to my web application (When user logs in, he/she should be able to see all his/her friends in my application as well
2. When user clicks on his/her Facebook friend from my application, I want to be able to extract friend's information as well (like movies, interests, likes and groups)

**In nutshell, 1) Extract one's friends list 2) Extract friend's information.**

My second question is that, How to initilize FacebookWebApplication object? In a post in StackOverflow, I saw an answer to use "DefaultFacebookWebApplication" but this class is not available in my dll.

Answer (score 0):

To your first question:

You'll want to get familiar with the Graph API http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api.

You will be making web requests to the Graph API and parsing a response composed of JSON.  There are several open source SDKs available to help you out.  I would reccomend this one:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/ee388574.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Hi Stephen, Unfortunately since yesterday I am reading and reading. However I am not getting any point to start. Open source SDKs are also so sometimes confusing. I was looking for a point to start. However thank you for reply.

Answer (score 0):

I would look at the newer Facebook C# SDK on CodePlex, it is actively supported & available as NuGet modules : http://facebooksdk.codeplex.com/ - or just search for "Facebook" in NuGet. Here is simple example using the SDK: http://facebooksdk.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Getting%20Started%20with%20an%20ASP.NET%20MVC%203%20Website